# How can I get what the recipient wrote in all the fields of a document?

Tags: docusignapi

I have been able to retrieve an image of the recipient's signature, but my documents have a lot of text fields and I would like to get what the recipients entered in each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ListEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) api with the `include_tabs=true` query string parameter.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients?include_tabs=true
```